# I see that this is true through computation but not proof

Tags: real-analysis, integration, summation

I am looking at the following problem to see if it is true. I have made up an example and computed it and I do see that is true. However, I would like to see how this is proved, as the proof is stumping me.

If $f: \{x \in R:x ≥  1\}  \to R$ is continuous then

$\sum_{i=1}^{n}{f(i)}= \int_{1}^{n+1}f(x) dx + \sum_{i=1}^{n}({f(i) - \int_{i}^{i+1}f(x) dx)}$

Comment: $$\int_1^{n+1} f(x)\,dx = \sum_{k = 1}^n \int_k^{k+1} f(x)\,dx.$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}{f(i)}= \int_{1}^{n+1}f(x) dx + \sum_{i=1}^{n}({f(i) - \int_{i}^{i+1}f(x) dx)}$$
Rearranged a bit gives
$$0= \int_{1}^{n+1}f(x) dx - \sum_{i=1}^{n}\bigg(  \int_{i}^{i+1} f(x)dx\bigg)$$
Going further, we get 
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\bigg(  \int_{i}^{i+1} f(x)dx\bigg) = \int_{1}^{n+1}f(x) dx$$

Let's split up the first.
$$\int_1^2 f(x)dx + \int_2^3 f(x)dx + \int_3^4 f(x)dx + \int_4^5 f(x)dx \; +... \int_n^{n+1} f(x)dx   $$
Notice the the integrals are just splitting up the domain from $1$ to $n+1$ into intervals of $1$, so the integrals can all be combined without loss of continuity into
$$\int_i^{n+1} f(x)dx$$
as desired.

Comment: I see that we will have equivalence with this, but how does the condition of continuity work itself into this proof

Comment: Is continuity just telling us the integral of f(x) exists and then we show equivalence through 0 = 0 and this is enough to suffice for a proof

Comment: @YesItsMario I updated my answer. Since $\int_a^b f(x)dx + \int_b^c f(x)dx = \int_a^c f(x)dx$ without loss of continuity, the solution holds. (Note: I believe you do have a problem with the summation of integrals if the limit of a function does not exist and the endpoints of integration, although the original integral should not be defined in that case anyway... haven't checked this, but that intuitively makes sense to me)